# Making wrapper/container responsive?

Tags: html, css, containers, wrapper

I having a lot of trouble trying to make a wrapper that contains an responsive image slider, I want it to scale down accordingly when the window is re-sized, but I can't get it to, the image slider wont scale down. Can somebody please please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

note* I only want to make it responsive on desktop and tablet down to 500px, mobile has a different look)

(I apologize if its sloppy, I'm new to this)

edit: heres a live link to it (not real images) : http://testjd.net46.net/
and the slider is overlapping the "Logo" when the browser windows is rezied can i stop this?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slider').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    prev:   '#prev', 
    next:   '#next', 
    timeout: 0, 
    rev: false 
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<img src="header.png" width="2022" height="82" alt="header"id="table">

<img src="footer.png" width="2022" height="109" alt="footer" id="table2"> 

<img src="Background.jpg" name="fsbg" width="2022" height="1460" id="fsbg">

<img src="title.png" alt="title" name="title" width="500" height="500" id="title">

<table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" id="table3" name="table3">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="500x500/Animal-Ambition-2-100percent-new-with-logo.gif" width="500" height="500" alt="aa"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Pilot.png" width="500" height="500" alt="pilot"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Smoke.png" width="500" height="500" alt="smoke"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Everytime I Come Around.png" width="500" height="500" alt="everytime i come around"><img src="500x500/50-Cent---Irregular-Heartbeat.gif" width="500" height="500" alt="irregular heartbeat"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Hustler.png" width="500" height="500" alt="hustler"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Twisted.png" width="500" height="500" alt="twisted"><img src="500x500/50 Cent - Winners Circle.png" width="500" height="500" alt="winners circle"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
    <div id="slider">
    <img src="500x500/Animal-Ambition-2-100percent-new-with-logo.gif" width="500" height="500" alt="AA"> 
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Pilot.png" width="500" height="500" alt="pilot">
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Smoke.png" width="500" height="500" alt="smoke">
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Everytime I Come Around.png" width="500" height="500" alt="everytime i come around">
    <img src="500x500/50-Cent---Irregular-Heartbeat.gif" width="500" height="500" alt="irregular heartbeat">
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Hustler.png" width="500" height="500" alt="hustler">
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Twisted.png" width="500" height="500" alt="twisted"> 
    <img src="500x500/50 Cent - Winners Circle.png" width="500" height="500" alt="winners circle">
    </div>
    <div class="controller" id="next"></div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'my font' ;
    src: url(fonts/CuttyFruty.ttf) 
}

#wrapper {
    display: block;
    max-width: 660px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%; 
    bottom: 0%; 
    right: 5%;
}

#container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 660px;
    overflow: aut;  

}

#prev {
    background-image: url(left%20button.png);

    background-position: center center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#prev:hover {
    background-image: url(left%20button%20grey.png);
}

#next {
    background-image: url(right%20button.png);
    background-position: center center;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#next:hover {
    background-image: url(right%20button%20grey.png);
}
#slider {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #666;
}
#fsbg {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1040px;
}
#shadow {
    display: block;
    height: 550px;
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 15%;
    position: fixed;
}

#table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 82px;
    z-index: ;
}
#table2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: -15px;
    position: fixed ;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#table3 {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute ;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
textem {
    color: #FFF;
}
.textem2 {
    color: #666;
    text-align: right;
    font: 16px "my font" ;
}

#title {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 55%;
    position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #wrapper, #container, #slider {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #wrapper, #container, #slider {
    padding: 0px !important;
    display: none !important;

  }

  #prev {
      width: 80px;
      height: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 20%;

      top: 65%;
      padding: 0px !important;
  }

  #next {
      width: 80px;
      height: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 20%;

      top: 65%;
      padding: 0px !important; 
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
  }

  #table3 {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute ;
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
  }

  #table1 {
      z-index: 50;
      top: 0;
      position: fixed;
  } 

  #table2 {
    z-index: 50;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
  }

}
```

Comment: You are using fixed widhts, try %.

Comment: ive tried that, can you look at my comment below to Ezaz & Zoe thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see an issue and it might be the issue at hand. It is probably so simple, everyone has overlooked it. I attached an image of a screen shot from the css file above. Your width (edit: not width, overflow) is supposed to be set to "auto", but you have "aut" written there.[Screenshot of CSS Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/invkc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Height and Width from your  tag and give it **width:100%**  through Css

Comment: thanks for that, i have just tried that and it didnt work, i changed every width to 100% and what happened was the slider jumped across the page, i think because the slider is in a wrapper im having problems but i dont know how to fix it. here is a live link to what ive made (not the real images) http://testjd.net46.net/ im trying the get the slider the scale with the browser and also it overlaps the "logo" which i need to fix

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues here.

First, do you mean responsive, or just fluid? If you're just looking for a fluid solution that stretches with the window size in a really basic way, @ezaz's suggestion to replace `width` attributes with `100%` is on the money.

If you're looking to go one step further, and push different styling based on the width of the browser, the you'll need to research [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). These will allow you to manipulate elements with greater control. For example, if you wanted to display smaller buttons on smaller screens, you can do something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #next {
        height: 500px;
        width: 80px;
        /* etc... */
    }
}

@media (max-width: 499px) {
    #next {
        height: 200px;
        width: 40px;
        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, responsive i think? i want it to scale down with the browser window so if i resized the window say 20px the slider would scale down 20px too. that didnt work for me, ive tried this:     
                    
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #wrapper, #container, #slider {
        height: 400px;
       
    }       
           
    is it because ive the slider in a wrapper that it wont scale down